# Disable evil mode in specific mode doesn't work half the time

Tags: org-mode, evil

I am using doom which has evil everywhere enable.

I tried the following two command which works previously in other mode, but now I have problem disable evil when I am in org agenda mode.

here is what I tried

```
(set-evil-initial-state! 'org-agenda-mode 'emacs)

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode #'turn-off-evil-mode nil t)
```

is there any other trick worth tring?

Comment: The question is unclear. What is not working? Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you see at each step, and what you expected/wanted to see instead.

Comment: I think my question is quite clear. but you are correct, I should provide my attempt with just vanilla emacs.

Comment: Are you asking about disabling `org-agenda-mode`? Are you asking about disabling `evil-mode`?  You mention both of those, in passing. Reread your question and I think you'll see that it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: fixed! thank you

Answer (score 0):

try `(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook #'turn-off-evil-mode nil)`

Comment: interesting. This is the correct answer. why local and global matter in this scenario? I though using local would be some what "safer" (less conflict). whatever the "safe" may mean. can you explain please?

Comment: never mind I am being silly. I truely think I put 'org-agenda-mode-hoook not 'org-agenda-mode. This is embarassing

Comment: @A-nakWannapaschaiyong I tried both local and global and global works on my side, and I'm not sure the order of local and global.